$K_1,K_2$ are isomorphic subfields of $L$ via $\sigma$, every polynomial $P(x)$ over $K_1$ have the same number of roots in $L$ as $\sigma(P(x))$?
Let $K_1,K_2$ be isomorphic subfields of $L$ via $\sigma:K_1\to K_2$, must every irreducible polynomial $P(x)$ over $K_1$ have the same number of roots in $L$ as $\sigma(P(x))$?

@Yathi Do you assume that we can always extend $\sigma:K_1 \to K_2$ to $\sigma:L\to L$?

Which cases can you do yourself? If $\sigma$ is a $K$-isomorphism and $L/K$ is Galois?

No, not always.

Let $K_1=K_2=\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt2)$, $\sigma(\sqrt2)=-\sqrt2$. Let $L=\Bbb{Q}(\root4\of2)\subseteq\Bbb{R}$. Then $P(x)=x^2-\sqrt2$ has two roots in $L$ whereas $\sigma(P(x))=x^2+\sqrt2$ has no real roots, and hence no roots in $L$.
OTOH, if $\sigma$ is a $K$-isomorphism for some $K\subseteq K_1\cap K_2$, and $L/K$ is Galois, then $\sigma$ extends to an automorphism of $L$, which quickly leads to an affirmative answer.
Undoubtedly something more precise can be said. I would need more time to come up with a general condition, but cannot invest the time right now.

The problem is that $K_1$, $K_2$ may be isomorphic, but not "sitting the same way" in $L$. Now, an example,
$K_1= L = k(t)$, and $K_2 = k(t^2)$, with the isomorphism $\sigma \colon t\mapsto t^2$. Now the polynomial $x^2-t$ has no roots in $L$, but $x^2-t^2$ has roots $\pm t$ in $L$.

A refreshingly different example!

I like the phrase "not sitting the same way". +1
